# How to launch tests in Chrome with the console docked at the bottom, not the right?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Whenever I launch Karma on Chrome a new Chrome window pops up. When I bring up the console on this Chrome Window the console comes up attached to the right side. I prefer the console attached to the bottom so I always bring it down - its kind of annoying.

How can I get Karma to launch Chrome with the console docked at the bottom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is no straightforward way to do that.

Although you [could specify](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher#configuration) custom launcher options for Chromium, there is [no option](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) that controls devtool position. (Though there is `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` that can also be handy in your case.)

However, there's a nice hack described in a related [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/35):

> A brute force approach is to pass the `--user-data-dir` flag to a custom launcher:

```
browsers: ['Chrome'],
customLaunchers: {
  Chrome_DevTools_Saved_Prefs: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--user-data-dir=./tests/config/.chrome_dev_user']
  }
}
```

> then

```
karma start --browsers Chrome_DevTools_Saved_Prefs
```

> This will allow you to reuse the profile. When you want to test using a fresh profile, use the default Chrome launcher or wipe the user-data-dir.

**UPDATE**: as @KFunk points out, this case is covered in [Karma's documentation](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher#configuration) in a bit nicer way:

```
customLaunchers: {
  Chrome_with_debugging: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    chromeDataDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '.chrome')
  }
}
```

Comment: There's also a cleaner way to do it, as described in the https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher readme using the chromeDataDir property

Comment: Using `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` did the job for me.